# Jetty can't find web application file

Tags: jetty, archlinux, jetty-9

I've installed jetty using `PKGBUILD` from AUR. The configuration was left default.

*Note: since `makepkg` was unable to download jetty v.9.3.2 from offical site, I downloaded it from maven repository*

The problem is that when I try to deploy my web application using Jetty Deployable Descriptor XML File, jetty fails to find the war with the following exception:

```
2016-01-27 17:05:30.265:WARN:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:main: Web application not found /home/pmitrofanov/sample.war
2016-01-27 17:05:30.265:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1efbd816{/sample,null,null}{/home/pmitrofanov/sample.war}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/pmitrofanov/sample.war
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Here is the contents of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/sample</Set>
    <Set name="war">/home/pmitrofanov/sample.war</Set>
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <!-- Max Form Size                                                   -->
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
    <Set name="maxFormContentSize">5000000</Set>
</Configure>
```

It should be mentioned that:

1. When I manually put the war into the webapps directory instead of using xml, everything goes fine.
2. All users have rwx access to the war: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 pmitrofanov pmitrofanov 25104375 Jan 27 16:37 /home/pmitrofanov/sample.war`

Comment: What is PKGBUILD and what is AUR? Is that something with archlinux?  Your XML deployable is for Jetty 9.0 not Jetty 9.3 (your DTD is off).  The maxFormContentSize setting of 5,000,000 is stupidly large for a form and opens you to a variety of DoS attack vectors.  What are you trying to accomplish? it's almost like you are following instructions for an old version of Jetty (pre Jetty 9).

Comment: The question is tagged with archlinux label, so yes - it is something with archlinux:) The XML deployable is used by multiple people with different versions of jetty (8 and 9). I can't tell you the reason of such big value of `maxFormContentSize`, since the creator of this xml isn't me. I don't think the format of deployable is the reason, because at least jetty could retrieve the path and fails only when trying to access war with the path.
p.s. nobody who works with this deployable has encountered this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that nobody except the owner has read+execute access to `/home/pmitrofanov` directory.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out...

- The Jetty XML format and syntax has changed for Jetty 9.3 it has [a new DTD](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-xml/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/jetty/xml/configure_9_3.dtd) (Highly encouraged you use it)
- [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)
- As of Servlet 3.x, if you are doing file uploads via POST, its better to use `@MultipartConfig` or `<multipart-config>` to define locations, sizes, limits, etc. (not the `WebAppContext` settings)
- As of Jetty 9, if you are working with large request headers (hinted at by your 5,000,000 byte max form content setting) you'll probably need to be aware of the Connector's [`HttpConfiguration`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html) which limits the request header sizes more severely then your `WebAppContext` settings.
- In your example, the `${jetty.base}/webapps/sample.xml` on startup it will immediately look for the war file, if it cannot find it it will not deploy.  (you are using a `${jetty.base}` with Jetty 9, right? you shouldn't be modifying/adding/deleting files in the jetty distribution, ever)
- Merely replacing the war will NOT redeploy the war file.  You'll have to touch the `${jetty.base}/webappps/sample.xml` to trigger a redeploy.
- There is no provision for monitoring resources referenced in the XML, only the content in `${jetty.base}/webapps/`